# "___ was a song sung by […]" or "___ was a song sang by […]"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, past-participles, participles

I'm aware that *sung* is the past participle of *sing*, while *sang* is the past tense form, but I'm still unsure on whether or not one would use the past tense or past participle verb in this sentence:

> "*[Subject (song)]* was a song [sang/sung] by [object1]."

Which verb form do I use here? (An explanation for future reference would be helpful too.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A song is sung not sang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing more research, I've come to this conclusion:
It is *sung* (the past participle), not *sang* (the past tense); according to the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, a past participle is as follows.

> the form of a verb, typically ending in *-ed* in English, that is used in forming perfect and passive tenses and sometimes as an adjective, e.g., *looked* in *have you looked?* and *lost* in *lost property*.

My example sentence is in a passive voice, as the subject (the song) undergoes the action (sing) (rather than an active voice, which "attributes the action of a verb or thing which it logically proceeds" (*New Oxford American Dictionary*, ᴀᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ sense 4)).

In other words, **the song is sung by the subject** rather than **the subject sang the song**.

An example of that sentence being worded in an active voice would be:

> "[Subject] sang the song [object 1 (song)]."

The subject becomes an object and the object becomes a subject.

**Passive voice**

> The song *More* is sung by Hasely.

**Active voice**

> Hasely sang the song *More*.

The dictionary definition I cited above also referred to a perfect tense. Perfect tenses are formed in English when one uses *had* or *have* (*They **have** been building since morning* (present perfect); *They **had** been building since morning* (past perfect); *They will have been building since morning* (future perfect).
*Been* is the past participle being used in those examples.

Past participles act as adjectives — if you can replace a verb with an adjective (like *likable*) while just leaving the necessary subjects and verbs, then the verb should be a past participle.

**This works:**

> *More* is awesome.

("by Hasley" isn't needed in the sentence as it already has a subject (***More***) and verb (**is**))

**But this doesn't:**

> Hasely likable [the song *More*].

By replacing the verb of the actively voiced sentence with an adjective, you aren't leaving any other verbs to keep the sentence valid.

Answer (score 2):

This is a past participle, there is no ambiguity here. Sung.
The song is sung, not sang.
You can truncate the sentence next time you have a doubt: you can write X was a song sung. But not X was a song sang.
He sang a song that was sung by him.